# How can I apply a base component's propTypes to a styled-component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, styled-components

Note that I am not using TypeScript, only JavaScript (jsx).

I am trying to style some buttons from a UI library using styled-components. When I try to implement that new styled button, the Intellisense in VSCode does not suggest any of the properties on the original component.

When implementing the Button directly, I can see the `icon` attribute/definition:

[image: 1]

However, when I try creating a styled Button component, Intellisense is no longer functioning:

[image: 2]

I have tried setting the `defaultProps` and `propTypes` of the styled component to that of the `Button` component, though this also does not work:

[image: 3]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this not possible without TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why is it happening so. Did you can try specifying proptypes like this for StyledButton ? It should work using this approach(even without typescript).

```
StyledButton.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string
};
```

Instead of assigning it `StyledButton.propTypes = Button.propTypes`.

You can check more about it on official documentation - [documentataion URL](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)